# R - dim(X) must have a positive length in R?

Tags: r

I want to compute the closest 10 values for a row with 140 columns. 
The following is the structure of the matrix
   1    2    3     4    5     .... 140
1 0.1 25.6  13.2 10.0 13.5        0.2

```
closest_10_neighbors<-t(apply(d2_d1_jac_sim[-1], 1, function(x) order(-x)[1:10]))
```

But I'm getting an error saying this

```
Error in apply(d2_d1_jac_sim[-1], 1, function(x) order(-x)[1:10]) : 
dim(X) must have a positive length
```

How do i prevent this error?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `d2_d1_jac_sim` is a matrix. When you do `d2_d1_jac_sim[-1]`, this is not a matrix anymore. Example:

```
> m = toeplitz(c(4,3))
> m
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    4    3
[2,]    3    4
> m[-1]
[1] 3 3 4
```

This is equivalent to

```
> x <- c(m)
> x
[1] 4 3 3 4
> x[-1]
[1] 3 3 4
```

What do you want to get when you do `d2_d1_jac_sim[-1]`? If you want to remove the first row, the syntax is `d2_d1_jac_sim[-1,]`.